# How to encapsulate/hide variadic template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

Consider

```
template<
          typename A, 
          template<typename, typename...> class B,
          typename C = default_type,
          typename ... D 
        > struct D : B<A,D...> 
{ /*text*/ };
```

now when the variadic argument `D` is not empty/void, the argument `C` must be defined explicitly even when `default_type` is desired.

I'm trying to avoid this situation, i.e. I want to define `C` explicitly only when it is not a `default_type`.

I was thinking about something like

```
template<
          typename A, 
          template<typename, typename...> class B,
          typename EncapsulatedVariadicD,              
          typename C = default_type              
        > struct D : B<A,EncapsulatedVariadicD::D...> 
{ /*text*/   };
```

but not sure if it is possible at all and if so then how to define  that `EncapsulatedVariadicD`.

Any alternative/working solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, when you need to encapsulate a list of types, you can use a `std::tuple`.

You could to this:

```
template <
  template <typename, typename...> class B,
  typename A,
  typename Pack
>
struct Base;

template <
  template <typename, typename...> class B,
  typename A,
  typename... D
>
struct Base<B, A, std::tuple<D...>>
{
  using type = B<A, D...>;
};

template<
  typename A,
  template<typename, typename...> class B,
  typename PackedD,
  typename C = default_type
>
struct D : Base<B, A, PackedD>::type
{ /*text*/ };
```

And use it like this:

```
D<SomeB, std::tuple<D1, D2>>
```

---

Quoting your comment:

> If `C` is not default and `PackedD` is empty then you have to provide it explicitly as `std::tuple<>` which otherwise can be a default value for this parameter. I just guess I can't have it both ways, is it true?

If you don't mind your template getting even more complex internally, you *can* have it both ways. Here's how:

```
// Unique type, internal marker for "use default template argument"
struct UseDefault {};

// GoalChooser has internal `type` which will hold the actual definition
template <
  typename A,
  template <typename, typename...> class B,
  typename Arg1,
  typename Arg2
>
struct GoalChooser;

template <
  typename A,
  template <typename, typename...> class B,
  typename C,
  typename... D
>
struct GoalChooser<A, B, C, std::tuple<D...>>
{
  struct type : B<A, D...>
  {
    // Your original definition of class template D goes here
  };
};

template <
  typename A,
  template <typename, typename...> class B,
  typename C,
  typename... D
>
struct GoalChooser<A, B, std::tuple<D...>, C>
{
  using type = typename GoalChooser<A, B, C, std::tuple<D...>>::type;
};


// GetArg applies appropriate default template arguments as applicable
template <
  typename Arg1,
  typename Arg2
>
struct GetArg
{
  using arg1 = Arg1;
  using arg2 = Arg2;
};

template <
  typename Arg
>
struct GetArg<UseDefault, Arg> : GetArg<Arg, UseDefault> {};

template <
  typename... T
>
struct GetArg<std::tuple<T...>, UseDefault>
{
  using arg1 = std::tuple<T...>;
  using arg2 = default_type;
};

template <
  typename C
>
struct GetArg<C, UseDefault>
{
  using arg1 = C;
  using arg2 = std::tuple<>;
};

template <>
struct GetArg<UseDefault, UseDefault>
{
  using arg1 = default_type;
  using arg2 = std::tuple<>;
};


// Client code will use this
template <
  typename A,
  template <typename, typename...> class B,
  typename Arg1 = UseDefault,
  typename Arg2 = UseDefault
>
using D = typename GoalChooser<
  A,
  B,
  typename GetArg<Arg1, Arg2>::arg1,
  typename GetArg<Arg1, Arg2>::arg2,
>::type;
```

The idea is that client code uses `D` (which has now become an alias template) and can pass either a `std::tuple` (indicating its `D...` parameter), or another type (indicating its `C` parameter), or neither, or both (in arbitrary order, even).

Application of appropriate default arguments is done by `GetArg`, and resolution of the alias is then handled by `GoalChooser`.

This assumes that the value for `C` can never be a `std::tuple`. If this is not an acceptable limitation, you can circumvent it by using a custom type instead of `std::tuple`, in the spirit of [krzaq's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40278226/1782465).

(Note that this solution no longer needs the `Base` helper from my first answer).

Comment: thanks! actually both solutions suffer from the opposite problem, i.e. if C is not default and PackedD (in your example) is empty then you have to provide it explicitly as `std::tuple<>` which otherwise can be a default value for this parameter. I just guess I can't have it both ways, is it true?

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky You *can* actually have it both ways; answer updated.

Comment: my apologize, I didn't get time to understand the offered solution as I moved from this point at the moment, so I'll accept the answer as is for now, but may ask a question when I get to it one day.

Answer (score 3):

Use a packed type, let's call it `type_list`. You can also use `std::tuple` if you don't need to care about keeping instances of it.

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct type_list{};
```

Then specialize your template for it:

```
template<typename A, template<typename, typename...> class B,
        typename TypeList, typename C = default_type>
struct D;

template<typename A, template<typename, typename...> class B,
         typename... TypesInTheList, typename C>
struct D<A,B,type_list<TypesInTheList...>,C> : B<A, TypesInTheList...>
{
    using parent = B<A, TypesInTheList...>;
};
```

You'd use it as expected:

```
D<int, some_b, type_list<float, char, double>>
```

[live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mzXL70oMVvcVbEeS)

Comment: Of course, `D` itself can be specialised. Much more elegant than mine.